# QAF 3.0.1b | Not picking test after upgrading QAF from 3.0.0 to 3.0.1b

Tags: java, maven, testng, qaf

When I upgraded my existing package in POM.xml (Maven) from QAF 3.0.0 to 3.0.1b my automation test stopped picking up the tests mentioned in testng.

```
Results :
Tests run: 0, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
```

All my tests are standard BDD (Gerkin) written and managed according to https://github.com/qmetry/qaf-blank-project-maven
Note: When I checked QAF latest repo all tests are written inside /test

```
My project structure  
/scenarios

/config/

/src/...

..etc
```

Below is my TestNg config

```
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd">
<suite name="test suite 1" verbose="0" parallel="none">
    <listeners>
        <listener class-name="com.proj.listener.proj_listener" />
    </listeners>
    
    <test name="Config-1" enabled="true">
        <parameter name="env.resources" value="resources;executions/exec_1"/>
        <groups>
        <run>
            <include name="@sit1" />
        </run>
        </groups>
        <classes>
            <class name="com.qmetry.qaf.automation.step.client.gherkin.GherkinScenarioFactory"/>
        </classes>
    </test>
    
</suite>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using [meta-data filter](https://qmetry.github.io/qaf/latest/scenario_metadatata_filter_include_exclude_prop.html). For example:

```
<test name="Config-1" enabled="true">
        <parameter name="env.resources" value="resources;executions/exec_1"/>
        <parameter name="include" value="{'groups':['@sit1']}"></parameter>
        <classes>
            <class name="com.qmetry.qaf.automation.step.client.gherkin.GherkinScenarioFactory"/>
        </classes>
</test>
```

Comment: Worked with the above changes.